# Pesquisa Acadêmica sobre o SOpt

Tags: debate, pesquisa, estudo-científico

Olá,

Venho por meio deste post vos pedir apoio a uma pesquisa sobre o uso do SOpt. A pesquisa está sendo realizada pela mestranda Isabel Amaral e o pesquisador Minhyung Kang na Universidade Ajou, na Coreia do Sul. E tem por objetivo verificar o que faz os usuários do SOpt constantemente compartilhar conhecimento através da comunidade. O foco também é na percepção dos usuários, basicamente no como vocês se sentem ao utilizar a comunidade.

A pesquisa estará disponível até o dia 31 de julho, sendo um pouco extensa possuindo 22 perguntas, mas que leva no máximo 10 minutinhos (na verdade em 7 minutos a grande maioria finaliza).

A idea é que através das suas respostas, uma análise estatística seja realizada para validar as hipóteses. Por isso, algumas perguntas são semelhates, mas isto acontece por causa do método utilizado. A análise deve ser completamente concluida em outubro/novembro quando disponibilizarei um link com o sumário dos resultados.

Você pode acessar a pesquisa aqui: https://pt.surveymonkey.com/r/stack_pt_m

**Esta pesquisa é completamente voluntária, mas sua participação seria extremamente apreciada.**

Obrigado pela atenção!
O meu contato para sugestões é isabelamaral@ajou.ac.kr.

Comment: "*ou preferível, posso transferir a posse desse post para a Isabel*", sinceramente eu acho melhor, justamente para não manter uma publicação extra oficial por alguém com diamante :D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Não acho uma má ideia. Meu principal motivo pra criar o post foi evitar que surgissem perguntas tipo "como um usuário com 0 rep criou o post? Porque foi criado pelo Gabe e dado pra ela". Melhor ser aberto logo do começo 

Comment: ou pode deixar isso claro em uma nota na própria pergunta ou aqui nos comentários :D

Comment: Eu votaria ainda em deixar como comentário por 1) não poluir a pergunta com algo que não faz parte do conteúdo da mesma e 2) possuir um permalink direto para caso seja necessário citá-lo em algum outro contexto.

Comment: Não consegui responder =P Travou ao clicar no "próximo"...

Comment: Oi Jefferson, verifiquei novamente o link e agora está funicionando sem problemas. Obrigada mesmo por tentar responder! E desculpa o incômodo
no problema do link.  :)

Comment: Contribuição efetuada. Sucesso com sua pesquisa.

Comment: Estamos aguardamos o resultado :)

Comment: Muito obrigada pela contribuição, @AugustoVasques! é um grande apoio para minha pesquisa. :)

Comment: @hugcsl com certeza! Farei tudo para que a análise seja rápida e possa disponibilizar os resultados o quanto antes. :D

Comment: Já fiz também, já tem pelo menos um Portuga lá ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. muito obrigada mesmo pela sua participação :D